# How to use web.config file in out of browser silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, web-config, out-of-browser

I have develop one silverlight Application which is out of browse application.

now my prob is in my application some server path is there so I have to set it on web.config file but I don't know how to use web.config file in out of browse application so can anyone please tell me what is the way I can get my web.config file on client side so I am able to use path which are mentioned in web.config file

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you use the [WebClient](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=webclient&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.net.webclient.aspx&ei=Bib_Ufi9NeioyAHEroG4DA&usg=AFQjCNEyQ1CIdPkY06o5irzsGd98N97zXg&bvm=bv.50165853,d.aWc) class to get the stuff you need? You need to give more details about what your doing or no one here can help you.

Comment: yes I have tried it but Exception occurred remote server not found.

Comment: Please see the Exception details while using weclient InnerException = {System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.NotSupportedException: The URI prefix is not recognized.
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   a...

Comment: You can send parameters in [InitParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc189004%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) if the parameters are not sensitive.

Comment: I have tried that the applicaiton is out of browser so testpage.aspx not initialize so initParametrs not getting at application startup event.